# Only show items fitting in the first n rows

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a collection with a dynamic number of items, ranging from 2 to 20.

They are displayed in wrapping rows with the following style rules:

```
flex-wrap: wrap
```

Number of items per row varies depending on the viewport's width.

Is there a way to limit number of visible rows to a certain number, e.g. 2?

Comment: flex-direction: row is by default, otherwise depends

Comment: max-height with overflow:hidden